# Best way to read data from another website

Tags: html, servlets

Here's the situation:

I have a web application (Java servlets) at "mycompany.com". A business partner is going to supply me with data from his application at "yourcompany.com".

His application is driven by a web form (POST). I know nothing about his application other than the results will always be returned via a web page.

For example, if I create a static HTML form with a submit button and send it to his web site, I get the results in my browser.

I can create that web form in my application, but now - how to I read the results from his web site?

Any ideas?

-R

Comment: Are you just dumping the content to screen, or do you have to process it first before anything else?

Comment: do you mean toy can cross-site-post?

Comment: I'm supposed to process the info coming back from the other site in my application.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to do some screen scraping - check out [XQuery for that](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/j-jtp03225.html).

Answer (score 0):

If he were up for upgrading how he does it, Web Services (specifically, SOAP) would be a standard, maintainable way to pass data between applications on a network.

Comment: I totally agree, but his site is not going to get updated any time soon. What I get is what I get. <joy>

Answer (score 0):

If you want finer control in the process and not to XMLize the HTML page, I would use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) + [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)